# Continuously spawn 4 squares on top of each other regardless of speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function that spawns 4 objects in a row and those objects move down.I want to keep spawning 4 objects on top of previous 4 objects, but I want to avoid having empty horizontal space between those rows. Think of it like a chess board or any board with squared scrolling downwards indefinitely, and the 4 objects that I keep spawning are chess board squares.

This is my current function that spawns 4 objects in horizontal and I have a coroutine that calls this in random intervals

```
public void CreateLetter()
{
    var wordLetters = randomChosenWord.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < letterPlacements.Length; i++)
    {
        var chosenLetter = wordLetters[Random.Range(0, wordLetters.Length)];
        //Do not spawn too much duplicates
        var numberOfSameLetters = FindObjectsOfType<LetterController>().Where(l => l.Letter == chosenLetter).ToList().Count;
        var lettersAlreadyChosen = FindObjectOfType<PlayerControls>().playerChosenLetters;
        //Did player choose any letter already? spawn that letter less
        if (numberOfSameLetters > (lettersAlreadyChosen.IndexOf(chosenLetter) != -1 ? 1 : 2))
        {
            var trimmedRandomWord = randomChosenWord.Trim(chosenLetter);
            chosenLetter = trimmedRandomWord[Random.Range(0, trimmedRandomWord.Length)];
        }
        GameObject letter = Instantiate(letterPrefab);
        letter.transform.position = new Vector2(letterPlacements[i].transform.position.x, letterPlacements[i].transform.position.y + 1);
        letter.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = letterSprites[alphabet.IndexOf(char.ToUpper(chosenLetter))];
        letter.GetComponent<LetterController>().Letter = chosenLetter;
    }
}
```

Should make a check if the new four square positions would collide with previous four? Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and calculating, I found out that what I need actually is called
**inverse proportion**.

To make the coroutine spawn 4 squares after the previous 4 have spawned (so that they are perfectly aligned), I use the movement speed of squares and then calculate the time when the coroutine should run again and spawn another 4 squares. In other words, the bigger the movement speed, the faster the coroutine function repeats:

```
IEnumerator GenerateLetters()
{
    while(randomChosenWord.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / (movementSpeed * 0.5f));
        CreateLetter();
    }
}
```

and this is the Update function in script attached to square prefab object:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Move letter downwards
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime / 2);
    gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = Letter.ToString();
}
```